# Python: I can not get pynput to install

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to run a program with pynput. I tried installing it through terminal on Mac with pip. However, it still says it's unresolved on my ide PyCharm. Does anyone have any idea of how to install this?

Answer (score 0):

I have three theories, but first: make sure it is installed by running python -c "import pynput"

1. JetBrain's IDEs typically do not scan for package updates, so try restarting the IDE.
2. JetBrain's IDE might configure a python environment for you, this might cause you to have to manually import it in your run configuration.
3. You have two python versions installed and you installed the package on the opposite version you run script on.

I think either 1 or 3 is the most likely.

Comment: Pycharm actually scans for packages updates and it works pretty well most of the time without having to restart the it. In some rare cases it is true that it has issues with referencing. In that case, one can try to do File -> Invalidate cache and restart.

More than two python versions, one can have several environments and install packages in an environment that is not the one chosen for the current project.